# how to create dynamic method with intellisense support

Tags: typescript

itemsApi = createApi in React reduxTool kit generates dynamic function slike use.., mutate.. etc. Such dynamically generated methods have full intelligence as well.

```
For example, if you have
createApi({...
    getItems: builder.query<any, string>({
                query: () => `items`,
            }),
...)}
```

createApi will return object with methods methods like useGetItemsQuery, useLazyGetItemsQuery etc.
These are not defined manually but dynamically constructed and that too with intellisense. How is this done in typescript?

As a simple example, how can I have a function that returns intellisenseEnable function based on some name passed?

Comment: you mean, function can have return type from the param?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is TypeScript generic. Because with generic we can infer a type from the parameter/argument.

Here's what I meant:

```js
function directlyTheSame<T>(param: T) {
    return param;
}

const willBeReturn = directlyTheSame({ foo:1337 });
// { foo: 1337 }
```

As you can see the return type of `directlyTheSame` is the param type itself. From this we can use it for more complex types, for example cherry-picking one field only.

```js
function iWantFooOnly<T>(param: {foo: T}) {
    return param.foo;
}

const someFoo = iWantFooOnly({foo: 1337});
// will be number
const someFoo2 = iWantFooOnly({foo: 'bar'});
// will be string
```

Or the other way, we going to returning object that have value from the param.

```js
function returningWhatIGot<T>(cb: () => T) {
    return {
        result: cb(),
    };
}

const resultObject = returningWhatIGot(() => 'foo');
resultObject.result; // will be string
const resultObject2 = returningWhatIGot(() => 1337);
resultObject2.result; // will be number
```

Furthermore, we can preprocess it first and then determine its return type based on the processing of the parameter using generics.

```js
type ParamType<Key extends string, Value extends string> = {
    key: Key;
    value: Value;
} & Record<Value, true>;

function repurposedType<Key extends string, Value extends string>(
    param: Record<Key, Value>
    ): ParamType<Key, Value> {

    const key = Object.keys(param)[0] as Key;
    const value = Object.values(param)[0] as Value;

    return Object.assign({}, {
        key: key,
        value: value,
    }, {
        [value]: true,
    } as Record<Value, true>);
}

const repurposed = repurposedType({hello: 'world'});
repurposed.key; // string with value 'hello'
repurposed.value; // string with value 'world'
repurposed.world; // true and not error on TypeScript
```

Comment: Hi. You've added great content for generics. My query is little different. When we pass T (meaning we explicitly know what's T), we can get T or properties. But in ReactToolKit, we create method like user and receive method getUser, lazyGetUser (new methods constructed on the fly with intellisense support)

Comment: I think RTK have similar approach to my last example, where we define both what param and return will be looks like. We just mapping generic from param to generic on return. or maybe can you write mini example of what you trying to achieve?